# Problem with importing CSV file to python (mac)

Tags: python, macos, numpy

This is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/hoodiej/Documents/PA5/ML/students/student-mat.csv', sep=";")
```

I get this error message:

> No such file or directory: '/Users/hoodiej/Documents/PA5/ML/students/student-mat.csv'

I ensure that I specify the path of my data file and I am not sure why it is not working.

Comment: Right click the file and get info. Make sure the path is correct. Also, is the program running on your local machine where the file is located?

Comment: Are you sure about that path and filename? Are you SUPER sure?

Comment: Yes, I am sure the path is correct. And the program is running on the file located local machine.

Answer (score 0):

`No such file or directory` means that one of the components in the path does not exist.

A typical cause of this would be an (invisible) character like a space at the beginning or end of a file or directory name.

Less likely but possible is that one of the file or directory names contains a unicode character that looks a lot like an ASCII but isn't.